# Disable clearing notification for my application

Tags: android, notifications

I need to write some application which will do some work in background. This application will be run from autostart and there wont be any start gui. Gui can be call from click on notification which will be showing with autostart. I worried that, when user clear notifications he lost opportunity to call this gui. My question is that is there any way to block clearing my notification by user?

Answer (score -6, accepted):

You want to implement a [Foreground Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html#Foreground).

Comment: A foreground service would work because it's "not a candidate for the system to kill when low on memory" and is required to show a notification.  But is it really a best practice to create a service solely for the purpose of displaying a notification that can't be cleared?  Kurro's answer seems far better.

Answer (score 23):

Here's a notification that won't allow the user to clear it.

```
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setTicker(r.getString(R.string.app_name))
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle(r.getString(R.string.app_name))
        .setAutoCancel(false)
        .setOngoing(true)
        .build();
```

The `setOngoing(true)` call achieves this, and `setAutoCancel(false)` stops the notification from going away when the user taps the notification.

The notification will be cleared if the application is uninstalled or by calling Cancel or CancelAll: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#cancel(int)

Comment: @ralphspoon please ask a new question and link to it here

Answer (score 4):

You might want to look into making a notification in the "running" section of the notifications. These notifications aren't cleared when the user clears them.

Use the [Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#FLAG_NO_CLEAR) AND [Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT). This should give you the effect you want

Comment: Is there really a reason to use both?  On Android 4.2.x, I'm using only Notification.Builder.setOngoing() and that by itself seems to prevent the notification from being cleared.  I was curious because I noticed that Notification.Builder doesn't seem to have a method that corresponds to FLAG_NO_CLEAR.

Answer (score 0):

Though @cja answer might be correct though he is missing some few lines of codes(Notification wont show or wont display on your notification tray).

This is the complete working function :

```
public void createNotification() {
    NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

    notification.setTicker( "Ticker Text" );
    notification.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    notification.setContentTitle( "Content Title" );
    notification.setContentText( "Content Text" );
    notification.setAutoCancel( false );
    notification.setOngoing( true );
    notification.setNumber( ++NotificationCount );

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
    notification.setContentIntent(pIntent);

    notification.build();  

    NotificationManager nManger = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nManger.notify(NotificationID, notification.build()); 
}
```

NotificationID is int serve as your notification's ID.

you can clear it by using this :

```
public void clear() {
    NotificationManager oldNoti = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    oldNoti.cancel( NotificationID );
}
```

make sure that `notification.setAutoCancel( false );` is set to **false** so it wont be cleared when clear button is pressed or when swipe gesture is present.

few lines of codes are originally from @cja post.

cheers / happy codings...

Comment: thanks @ralphgabb I tried using the same but still I'm able to clear the notification by clicking on clear all and swipe gesture. I'm developing on minimum API level 19 and target API Level 25

Comment: thats weird, ill try to check that out, this function really works on my end (used on multiple projects) or you can post a few lines of your code here.

Answer (score 0):

Just add these two flags to the notification, *FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL* prevent notification automatically dismissed when the user touches it and *FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT* make it an [Ongoing Notification](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT).

```
notification.flags=Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL|Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
```

Answer (score 0):

using this alone works perfectly for me  *Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR*
along with
notification.SetOngoing(true);

notification.SetAutoCancel(false);